# Build successful but missing symbols upon runtime

Tags: libraries

After building kmscon, I try to run it but get the error message:

```
% ./kmscon
/home/janus/kmscon/.libs/lt-kmscon: symbol lookup error: /home/janus/kmscon/.libs/libuterm.so.1: undefined symbol: xkb_state_get_keymap
```

Full terminal log here:
https://gist.github.com/ysangkok/5363162

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by

- changing `#include <xkbcommon/xkbcommon.h>` to `#include "xkbcommon/xkbcommon.h"`
- configuring with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/libxkbcommon/" ./configure`
- `ln -s ~/libxkbcommon/xkbcommon ~/kmscon/xkbcommon`.

Comment: Could you care to expand the answer with why it worked? E.g.
`#include <xkbcommon/xkbcommon.h>` searched in standard places. It did not find it and rather then point to a new location I just copied it to my homedir (ok, you softlinked it) and I told the include to search in a specific hard coded path.